# Set default value for parameter of List<string> type in function

Tags: c#, string, list

I write this code :

```
 private bool test(List<string> Lst = new List<string>() { "ID" })
    {

        return false;
    }
```

i want to set default value for "Lst" but has an error from "new" key word.
any idea?

Comment: Can you not set the value in the constructor of your object?

Comment: You can't set default parameter value of a reference-type explicitly, try `default(List<string>)` instead.

Comment: yes.where is i set value?@BDH

Comment: @xtnd8 what did you mean?

Comment: @Mohadeseh_KH I mean `List<string> Lst = default(List<string>)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Currently it's not possible in C# to initialize parameters with new objects or classes.

You can leave default value as `null` and in your method create your class instance:

```
private bool test(List<string> Lst = null)
{
    if(Lst == null)
    {
       Lst = new List<string> { "ID" };
    }
    return false;
}
```

In C# 8 we could shorten this kind of expressions with the new null conditional operator:

```
private bool test(List<string> Lst = null)
{
    Lst ??= new List<string> { "ID" };
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the default to null and then set this to your desired default in the first line

```
private bool test(List<string> Lst = null)
{
    List<string> tempList; // give me a name
    if(Lst == null)
         tempList = new List<string>() { "ID" };
    else 
         tempList = Lst;

    return false;
}
```

Now you can use `tempList` in your desired way

Comment: Note: I'm not a fan of this since it is unclear to the developer that this will actually use this fake list rather than null

Comment: @Downvoter: Please explain?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. See the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) for allowed values.

A possible alternative is to use overrides and/or a default value of null instead. Use either:

```
// Override
private bool test()
{
    return test(new List<string>() { "ID" });
}

// default of null
private bool test(List<string> Lst = null)
{
    if (Lst == null) {
        Lst = new List<string>() { "ID" };
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: You can ommit the default-value for the seond method.

Answer (score -1):

Not quite sure what you want to achieve, but you can use ref to initialize the list if it is null.

```
void SetDefault(ref List<string> list)
{
    if(list == null)
    {
        list = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Comment: He might actually need the list to be null in specific use-cases, which i also guess is why this answer was downvoted. 
At my work specifically, we check for null to differentiate when a use gave an input or not. If you automatically initialize the list magically somewhere you would break the kind of logic i'm talking about.